# JSQMessagesViewController change language for send button textview placeholder

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I wonder how I can change the language for send button text in JSQMessagesViewController.

Reading on the pod I see "Localized in over 15 languages" but how can I chnage the language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the language of the mobile device (iPhone, iPad etc.) the language of `JSQMessagesViewController` will automatically change. Will default to default language of the device (if supported).

Comment: Ah okey, is there any other way I can add my language? I dont find swedish in the list

Comment: It's should be possible, I haven't done it myself yet. But you can find more info here: https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/issues/784